# DataTables warning when renaming dataframe columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm having a hard time figuring out why I'm receiving this warning when I'm trying to reassign column names in R.

```
invest <- data.frame(cbind(1990:2015, investssa, investemde))
names(invest) <- c("year", "ssa", "emde")
```

Running this yields a pop-up warning in RStudio saying:

> DataTables warning: table id=rsGridData - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

I have gone to the website in the error message, but that doesn't really help. I have also tried to use rename() method from plyr, but it doesn't appear to do anything when I try it. Is there some other preferred way to rename columns in an R dataframe?

Comment: see http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_columns_in_a_data_frame/

Comment: Check the `str(investssa)` and `str(investemde)`  Also, you don't need `data.frame(cbind`, just `data.frame(..` is enough

Comment: First, `1990:2015` is not an appropriate variable name, if this is part of an original column of a dataframe, df, then use `invest <- cbind.data.frame(df$"1990:2015", df$investssa, df$investemde)` and use `colnames(invest) <- c("year", "ssa", "emde")`.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the error. I'm a dummy and had opened up the dataframe in RStudio (I do it using the GUI, but the equivalent is to use the View command). I guess when you have the dataframe open, and then you try to change the column names, or alter the dataframe's innate characteristics, you get this warning.

Comment: The best place for thanks (some people disapprove of posting them, but I don't mind) is under the answer(s) in question.

Comment: Just ran into this situation - confusing because I wasn't even using DataTable. Too bad RStudio doesn't catch this error and convert it into something more user friendly

Answer (score -1):

cbind is not needed inside the dataframe function.

try this ->

```
invest <- data.frame(A = 1990:2015, B = investssa, C = investemde)
colnames(invest) <- c("year", "ssa", "emde")
```

or

```
invest <- data.frame(year = 1990:2015, ssa = investssa, emde = investemde)
```

i think this will help...

Comment: OP's syntax is unusual, but I don't think that you've demonstrated a relationship between that and the error they are getting